# Slow Azure Table Search and Insert Operations on small tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to benchmark search/read & insert queries on an ATS which is small size(500 entities). Average insert time is 400ms and average search + retrieve time is 190ms.

When inserting, I am querying on the partition key and the condition itself is only composed of one predicate : [PartitionKey]  eq `<value>` (no more ands/ors). Also, I am returning only 1 property.

What could be the reason for such results?

Search code:

```
TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> projectionQuery = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Select(new string[] { "State" });
        projectionQuery.Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "" + msg.PartitionKey));
        // Define an entity resolver to work with the entity after retrieval.
        EntityResolver<bool?> resolver = (pk, rk, ts, props, etag) => props.ContainsKey("State") ? (props["State"].BooleanValue) : null;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        List<bool?> sList = table.ExecuteQuery(projectionQuery, resolver, null, null).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
```

Insert Code:

```
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Messages");
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(msg);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        // Execute the insert operation.
        sw.Start();
        table.Execute(insertOperation);
        sw.Stop();
```

Comment: Try to ping your nearest Azure server. Issue can be in your connection. however ~200ms is pretty adequate retreive time for my taste.

Comment: Can you please clarify where you're running your test code from? That is, is it running from code deployed to Azure? And if so, is the code executing in the same region as the storage account?

Comment: The reason why you can only get one property is you're using EntityResolver, try to remove that. Refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx for the usage of EntityResolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this post for possible performance issues: [Microsoft Azure Storage Performance and Scalability Checklist](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/).

The reason why you can only get one property is you're using [EntityResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj733144.aspx), please try to remove that. Refer to [Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Tables Deep Dive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx) for the usage of [EntityResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj733144.aspx) - when you should use it and how to use it correctly.

Comment: Returning one property was a desired feature. I understand the usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SLA Document](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/):

> Storage
>
> We guarantee that at least 99.99% of the time, we will successfully
>   process requests to read data from Read Access-Geo Redundant Storage
>   (RA-GRS) Accounts, provided that failed attempts to read data from the
>   primary region are retried on the secondary region.
>
> - We guarantee that at least 99.9% of the time, we will successfully process requests to read data from Locally Redundant Storage (LRS),
>     Zone Redundant Storage (ZRS), and Geo Redundant Storage (GRS)
>     Accounts.
> - We guarantee that at least 99.9% of the time, we will successfully process requests to write data to Locally Redundant Storage (LRS),
>     Zone Redundant Storage (ZRS), and Geo Redundant Storage (GRS) Accounts
>     and Read Access-Geo Redundant Storage (RA-GRS) Accounts.

And also from there [refereed document](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=517017&clcid=0x409):

> Table Query / List Operations
>     **Maximum Processing Time:** Ten (10)
>   seconds (to complete processing or return a continuation)

There is no commitment for fast / low response time. Nor are there any commitments on being faster with smaller tables.

Comment: I understand, but is this normal behaviour? Do people, on an average, get the same results that I am getting? If not, is there something that is wrong with the way I am going about the benchmarking?

Comment: well, to get most out of Table storage you should specify`PartitionKey` **and**  `RowKey` together. 
Also check the https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/best-practices-performance/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#tables